# unexpected network loopback device on linux

Tags: linux, networking, home-networking, loopback

executing `ifconfig` I found network loopback device which was not expected to show (maybe some linux packages created it on it's own?) but I would like to analyze it what it does - any ideas how to track which process uses it and what it does, if it uses any files to keep some log etc? one of ideas is that it's malicious creation of some 3rd party so I would like to know what it does, other is to be able to access local Ipython notebook but I would like to be sure what is the purpose of this device **on my machine**

below `ifconfig` result

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu [[some_mtu]]
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 787  bytes 46448 (45.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 787  bytes 46448 (45.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: I would say `lo` is very expected.

Comment: You can edit the question all you wish, but it is on EVERY Linux machine, the answer is given in the link to the duplicate question: It's a virtual network interface that your computer uses to communicate with itself. It is used mainly for diagnostics and troubleshooting, and to connect to servers running on the local machine.

Answer (score 0):

From RFC 5735:

> > 127.0.0.0/8 - This block is assigned for use as the Internet host
> >     loopback address.  A datagram sent by a higher-level protocol to an
> >     address anywhere within this block loops back inside the host.  This
> >     is ordinarily implemented using only 127.0.0.1/32 for loopback.  As
> >     described in [RFC1122], Section 3.2.1.3, addresses within the entire
> >     127.0.0.0/8 block do not legitimately appear on any network anywhere.

The loopback interface is on almost every system that I used. It is present on all Linux systems and also on Windows (eventhough `ipconfig /all` on Windows 10 doesn't show it for some reason, it is still pingable).